# Learning VB and have basic math syntax error

Tags: vb.net

Here is my expression, i do not understand what is wrong in the code

```
    If damagedealt1 > fleet1hp Then
        damagedealt1 / fleet1hp = dfleet1loss

    End If
```

The error message is 'Expression is not a method'

Comment: did you mean `dfleet1loss = damagedealt1 / fleet1hp`?

Comment: What's wrong is that it's not a valid mathematical expression. What are you expecting it to do?  That's rather relevant information, don't you think?

Comment: I hate to say this, but it is clearer in C# where the equality operator is `==` and the assignment operator is a single `=`. In Algebra x=y is the same as y=x but in programming you are assigning the value on the right to the variable on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
damagedealt1 / fleet1hp = dfleet1loss
```

This line is is incorrect. It seems you have written it the wrong way round. The below line what you are looking for

```
dfleet1loss = damagedealt1 / fleet1hp
```

Comment: Oof yeah it was very late at night. Thanks for the obvious though!